# Storage tiering and SLA models

Tags: storage

I've started looking at switching storage charging models. Historically - it's been purely per-gig, in a big shared pool.

But I'm looking at extending the model, and looking at tiering storage offerings - mostly because we're looking at an investment in SSD - but under our previous charging model, we've not really been able to justify it. (We have got some as a 'controller cache upgrade').

My initial start point is to:

- Take a 'storage chunk'. Probably a RAID group, but maybe 'a shelf' or 'a controller'.
- Sum up the usable gigs.
- Sum up the theoretical IOPs of the spindles (random read and write penalty writes)
- Sum up theoretical MB/sec throughput of the spindles.

Divide IOPs and throughput by available TB, to set a 'performance allocation' based on each TB 'bought'. And look at a sample SATA configuration, sample FC/SAS configuration and SSD.

Now, this is rather a simplification I know - and is rather a worst case scenario, in a world of big fat caches and assorted other bottlenecks.

I've got a big pile of 'average usage' performance stats, and know what my real world cache hit ratios look like - but am now a bit stuck as to how to 'scale' this. As an example - my NetApp Filers are giving me 20-25% read cache miss rates, and does something entirely different with write cache and WAFL that makes that element hard to compare. (But I think assuming a high write cache-hit is not unreasonable, and thus allowing me to disregard write penalty and burst write latency).

So this is my question - what approach would you suggest for putting together say, 3 tiers of 'storage offering' (Archive, 'standard' and high performance)? How would you factor in the expected returns of caching and consolidation benefits?

Regarding storage tiering - that's an option, because it's effectively what we're doing already by big controller caches. But there's still a need for differentiating 'cheap' and 'fast' storage, and I'm needing and appraoch for that too.

Comment: If you look at 3Par storage not only will it allow for automatic tiering on a per-block level based on set profile or actual usage but it can report on this for charging :)

Comment: I've got a few 3PARs, and my other options are VMAX tiered. I figured tiering the storage muddied the water a bit. But the same principle applies - if my array is 10% SSD, 40% FC and 50% SATA - how do I give some customers 'priority' and others 'cheap'? NetApp will let me do hybrid aggregates with an SSD + FC chunk too.

Comment: Well based on either their manual choice/request or automatically based on usage profile.

Comment: So would you advocate auto/request tiering and chargeback? That may be difficult in the environment, because we've usually sold based on a capital expenditure model, but I can give it a shot.

Comment: To be honest it's not the technical side of things that worries me here, it's the commercial legal side that I'd run away from - good luck!

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem. I'll quite happily build a million iops array (or 5) if someone'll give me the budget. I just need to convince them to give me the budget :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer here is to charge per TB and base your price on what it cost you to provide it. Have one class of storage which is drives and SSD, another class for just drives, and modifiers for other services (like how they're backed up, whether they're replicated, etc). In this environment, if you even come up against a performance wall based on the composition of your pool, you need to pay for additional SSD without necessarily having someone to pass that onto.

If you want to get into the business of having some sort of SLA for performance, you'd need QOS. Some platforms allow you to cap certain workloads in terms of some metric, which would be something that allows you to enforce being a good neighbor, as well as charge heavy users with a low volume of storage proportionally to what they cost you to host.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines. I was less sure whether a hard metric was worth giving,  given I've customers who _think_ they want guaranteed performance.

Comment: QOS, at least on Netapp, works the other way. It limits performance, but doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: Yes, I'm still unsure whether QoS is a fit and proper solution to any particular problem. Limiting performance per customer sort of depends how big a pie you have in the first place. And part of the beneficial advantage of consolidated storage is that contention allows better burst for lower average. I'm wondering if a monthly bill per IOP wouldn't be better, if I can convince them to switch to revenue from capex.

Comment: The benefit is that it prevents one app from making everyone else's latency higher. I would almost recommend capping all workload to maybe 75% what the box can do, just to ensure that spikes never hit anyone else.

Comment: "How much can a box do" is another awkward question I find :)

Comment: It can be, especially with SSD making two workloads on the same hardware bottleneck at two completely different levels. You can get a blurry number by measuring latency under various types of loads. Alternatively, you can apply a number that's definitely way lower than the box is capable of spiking to but high enough for your clients. And when your phone rings, you'll be guaranteed it's because someone's hitting their QOS limit, not a box limit.